# Link between scala object, dataset and dataframe

Tags: json, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, playframework

I have created the following case class:

```
case class Data(ads:Option[Ads])

case class Ads(subject: Option[String]
           , body:Option[String]
           , price:Option[Int]
           , location:Option[Location]
           , attribut:Option[Seq[Attribut]]
 )

case class Location(city:Option[String]
                , zipcode:Option[String])

case class Attribut(key_label:Option[String]
                , value_label:Option[String]
)
```

And I parse a JSON format (part of a HTML) with play framework.

I finally obtain an Object Ads

```
JsSuccess(Ads(Some("Subject"), SOme("Body"), Some(Price), Some(Location(Some("City"), Some("Zipcode")), Some(Attribut("key_label", "value_label"))
```

I want to save this in a CSV file in the following way:

```
Subject   Body           Price   City  Zipcode  Key_Label  Value_Label
Play      Playing games  532     Geneve 95      GEN        Gen2
```

I convert the object into a List of `Ads(Some("Subject"), Some("Body"), Some(Price), Some(Location(Some("City"), Some("Zipcode")), Some(Attribut("key_label", "value_label")`  and convert this list into a DataFrame.

But I have only one column Value which contains all the elements of the object.

```
    Value
    (Some("Subject"), SOme("Body"), Some(Price), Some(Location(Some("City"), Some("Zipcode")), Some(Attribut("key_label", "value_label")
```

Has someone got an idea please ?
I don't really understand how to link scala object with dataset and dataframe.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: How did you convert the `List` into the `DataFrame`? Also, I believe there would be better alternatives for writing a local CSV file rather than pulling out **Spark**.

Comment: Its unclear why you would want to use Spark with single JSON file. If you do `df.printSchema()` it probably shows it has single column `Value` which is a struct. If yes, you just need to unpack/ flatten it. You can unpack by using `.withColunn(...,...)` or flatten as in the above example

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  I finally think that it's not necessary to use Spark. I want the convert JsSuccess(Ads(Some("Subject"), SOme("Body"), Some(Price), Some(Location(Some("City"), Some("Zipcode")), Some(Attribut("key_label", "value_label"))  into a CSV file with 7 columns : Subject, Body, Price, City, ZIpcode, Key_Label and Key_value. Any ideas ?

Comment: I did like this:                                                                                                           implicit class CSVWrapper(val prod: Product) extends AnyVal {
        def toCSV: String = prod.productIterator.map{
            case p: Product =>  p.toCSV
            case rest => rest
        }.mkString("|")
    }

Answer (score 0):

Comments are helpful, but the generic flattening function may not output columns in the desired order, and/or handle putting array elements into their own separate columns.

Supposing your JSON file contains lines such as:

```
{"ads": {"subject": "abc", "body": "doing something", "price": 13, "location": {"city": "Houston", "zipcode": 39014}, "attribut": [{"key_label": "a", "value_label": "b"}]}}
```

If the file is fairly consistent and you're already including Spark as a dependency, you *probably* do not need to use a separate library to parse the JSON.

You will need to use the `explode` function to handle the fact that the "attribut" column is a list. Use the `explode_outer` function instead, if the lists may be empty but you would like to preserve other columns' values.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
// assuming spark is the Spark Session
val df = spark.read.json("mydata.json")

val df1 = df.select(col("ads.subject").alias("Subject"), col("ads.body").alias("Body"),
          col("ads.location.city").alias("City"), col("ads.location.zipcode").alias("Zipcode"),
          explode(col("ads.attribut")))

val resultDF = df1.select(col("Subject"), col("Body"), col("City"), col("Zipcode"),
               col("col.key_label"), col("col.value_label"))
```

`resultDF.show` would output:

```
+-------+---------------+-------+-------+---------+-----------+
|Subject|           Body|   City|Zipcode|key_label|value_label|
+-------+---------------+-------+-------+---------+-----------+
|    abc|doing something|Houston|  39014|        a|          b|
+-------+---------------+-------+-------+---------+-----------+
```

To output as a single CSV file in the specified directory, with headers:

```
resultDF.repartition(1).write.option("header", "true").csv("/tmp/my-output-dir/")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  I finally think that it's not necessary to use Spark. I want the convert JsSuccess(Ads(Some("Subject"), SOme("Body"), Some(Price), Some(Location(Some("City"), Some("Zipcode")), Some(Attribut("key_label", "value_label"))  into a CSV file with 7 columns : Subject, Body, Price, City, ZIpcode, Key_Label and Key_value. Any ideas ?